# Which of these options is better in performance in iOS? (UIWebView)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

1. A UIWebView with a transparent background and a custom background setted in the view.background.
2. A UIWebView with the custom background loaded from CSS code.

I am using the custom background image in all the views of my app with imageNamed, so I think it is cached. But I'm not sure if the webView in the second option is loading a new resource every time it loads (since it's loaded using html). Does the iOS webkit do a resource caching?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it doesn't matter. Image resources are usually cached when you fetch them using an `UIImage` initializer, and `UIWebView` also caches images in it's browser cache.

Comment: But when y press back in the navigation controler and the webview is deallocated and I push it again the webView will load the resource as new or the webCache remains?

Comment: The web cache is a 'global' (singleton) object. `[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]`.

Comment: Do I have to use that NSURLCache to use the cache? Or it is does automatically? By now I haven't configured explicitly a web cache.

Comment: The web view automatically uses the shared URL cache.